# Using xmlrpc in web2py for command line interface for a web application

Tags: python, xml-rpc, command-line-interface, web2py

I have an application in web2py. To create the command line interface of the gui (web-interface), I want to use xmlrpc service. For example if I have following function :

```
@auth.requires_login
def example():
    temp = request.args[0]
    //do something on temp
    return dict(temp=temp)
```

How can I call this function in xmlrpc, so that I make minimal changes in my original function definition (I require to do authentication, somehow send the request variable, and have some returned data structure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use service to expose function with xmlrpc

```
auth.settings.allow_basic_login = True

@service.xmlrpc
def example(temp):
    return ...


@auth.requires_login()
def call(): return service()
```

You can read more in the book.